# Revert the revert(un-revert) doesn't realize file changes in git?

Tags: git, git-revert

How to revert the revert in general?

I used `git revert -m 1 <commit-ID>` to revert the reverted changes, and then pushed.

But I am not seeing any changes in my PR.

[image]

If I compare the `master` branch and the PR branch, I am able to see the differences and realize the PR has the correct commits that I am expecting.

[image]

How can you explain this and assuming this worked correctly?

Answer (score 1):

First, a bit of a side note: a revert that requires `-m` is reverting (undoing) a *merge commit*.  That's why it requires the `-m` flag, to tell Git which parent to use.  Commits that have multiple parents—i.e., merge cmmits—can't be shown as *changes* without some sort of redefinition of "changes" or other trickery.  (That's what the `-m` is about: trickery to obtain a redefined "changes" so that the changes can be backed out.)

That aside, your PR branch appears to consist of exactly two commits:

- First, there's a revert commit.  This backs out some changes.
- Then there's a revert of the revert.  This backs out the backing out of the changes: the result is that the changes are back in.

Given:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- pr
```

where commit `I` undoes `H` and then commit `J` undoes `I`, i.e., redoes `H`, we should expect the files *in* `H` to exactly match the files *in* `J`.  That is, checking out commit `H` with:

```
git switch main
```

will produce some set of files, and then checking out commit `J` with:

```
git switch pr
```

will produce *the exact same set of files*.  So comparing `main` (commit `H`) vs `pr` (commit `J`) would have zero files that are different, which is what you see.  Here it doesn't matter whether `H` is actually a merge commit, except that to get `I` as a revert *of* `H` you would need the `-m 1`:

```
...--F
      \
       H   <-- main
      / \
...--G   \
          \
           I--J   <-- pr
```

If commit `I`'s snapshot is the result of `git revert -m 1 main`, and commit `J`'s snapshot is the result of `git revert <hash-of-I>` or equivalent, it's *very likely* that the files in `J` match the files in `H`.  However, due to the fact that `git merge` can have conflicts, and reverting the merge can then produce further conflicts that could be resolved differently in `I` than they were when `H` was set up, it's possible (just unlikely) that `J`'s snapshot would not match `H`'s.